# use LAG with expression in oracle

Tags: oracle, lag

I have a column **(status)** in a table that contain numbers and values are 1, 2 or 4.
I would like, in a SQL query, add a calculated column **(bitStatus)** that will store the bitwise oerator OR for the status column of the current line and the column in the previous line.

like so :

```
| id | status| bitStatus| 
|----|-------|----------|
| 1  |   1   |   1      |
| 2  |   2   |   3      |
| 3  |   4   |   7      |
| 4  |   1   |   7      |
```

So what I did is to use LAG function in oracle but I coudn't figure out how to do it as long as I want to create only on calculated column **bitStatus**

my query is like :

```
select id, status, 
BITOR(LAG(bitStatus) OVER (ORDER BY 1), status)) AS bitStatus
```

But as you know, I can't use LAG(bitStatus) when calculating bitStatus.

So how could I make it the desired table.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

- lines #1 - 6 represent sample data
- the `TEMP` CTE is here to fetch `LAG` status value (to improve readability)
- the final `select` does the `BITOR` operation as `bitor(a, b) = a - bitand(a, b) + b`

---

```
SQL> with test (id, status) as
  2    (select 1, 1 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 2 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 1 from dual union all
  5     select 4, 4 from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select id, status,
  9                lag(status) over (order by id) lag_status
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select id,
 13         status,
 14         status - bitand(status, nvl(lag_status, status)) + nvl(lag_status, status) as bitstatus
 15  from temp
 16  order by id;

        ID     STATUS  BITSTATUS
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         2          2          3
         3          1          3
         4          4          5

SQL>
```

Comment: I think I missed to mention that for a raw n I have to find the value of all bitand of n-1 previous raw !!